# Bootstrap styles overwrite Angular material design

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a button on my page combined with styles from bootstrap. My styles import the bootstrap.min just like this at the beginning:

```
@import "../../../../bootstrap.min.css"; // Bootstrap
```

But unfortunately the bootstrap styles for a button element overwrite the Angular styles. My button looks like this in the html:

```
<button mat-flat-button color="primary" (click)="submitDialog()">
    New submission
</button>
```

It should look like this on the page:
[image]

But because bootstrap overwrites the button element with styles, it is looking like this (way smaller, not rounded...):[image]

Comment: Firstly never use multiple frameworks since its obvious these issues will happen. 
Secondly inspect the button and remove/reset/edit the styles. Put the new style on .scss or on styles.scss to style them globally.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, is not recomended to use two framweroks, but if you still need it, go to your angular.json and in styles, set angular-material after bootstrap.min.css